# Refactor merged query in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I currently have 2 methods which carry out search queries both ways then they are merged together to retrieve the result.

#### Model relation

```
public function linkedTo() {
    return $this->hasMany(Linked::class, 'team_id');
}

public function linkedFrom() {
    return $this->hasMany(Linked::class, 'linked_id');
}
```

**Query**

```
$linkedTo = $team->linkedTo()->with(['games' => function ($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', "%$search%");
}])->get();

$linkedFrom = $team->linkedFrom()->with(['games' => function ($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', "%$search%");
}])->get();

$links = $linkedTo->merge($linkedFrom);
```

To get the result I need from the search results I had to merge these together.

Is there a cleaner way to join these together within one query?

Comment: It would be cleaner to assign the function you use in `with` to a variable e.g. `$callback = function ($query) use ($search) ...` and re-use it in both queries. Other than that there may be more things to do but they will really depend on you data structure and what you are actually trying to retrieve.

Comment: @apokryfos do you have an example of this? struggling with the format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reduce code duplication (but not actually change what is executed) you can do this:

```
$filter = function ($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', "%$search%");
};
$linkedTo = $team->linkedTo()->with(['games' => $filter ])->get();
$linkedFrom = $team->linkedFrom()->with(['games' => $filter ])->get();
$links = $linkedTo->merge($linkedFrom);
```

Comment: Yeah that reduces my methods down without a change in output.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `union`:

```php
// First build the queries, note I removed 'get()'
$linkedTo = $team->linkedTo()->with(['games' => function ($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', "%$search%");
}]);

$linkedFrom = $team->linkedFrom()->with(['games' => function ($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', "%$search%");
}]);

// Now union and get the results
$links = $linkedTo->union($linkedFrom)->get();
```

More details here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#unions